# Unable to perform Drag and Drop action in Android using Appium

Tags: android, appium, appium-ios

I am unable to perform drag and drop action using below code in Android Hybrid App using Appium.

Platform : Appium with windows

**Option 1**

```
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(ele1).moveTo(ele2).release.perform();
```

**Option 2**

```
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(ele1).moveTo(ele2, 252, 180).release.perform();
```

**Option 3**

```
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(ele1, 252, 152).moveTo(ele2, 252, 180).release.perform();
```

> Appium version: 1.4.13 ; Android OS: 4.4.2

Error: Appium throws an error like it did not perform drag action successfully.

> --- log appium server ----  info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"Did not drag successfully","status":13}

Note: I tried in both Horizontal and Vertical perspective but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instruments to record your drag and drop gesture and use the generated uiautomation scripts in JAVASCRIPT executor ..

1. Open your instruments (sub ide of xcode)
2. Choose your simulator with the hybrid app
3. Choose record option in instruments
4. Manually perform drag and drop gesture
5. Uiautomation scripts for corresponding gesture will get generated
6. Copy the script and use in JavaScriptexecutor and execute the code

Comment: Hi sunder 

Thanks for your comments.  I am using appium(android) with windows.  Could you please explain how that has to be done in windows ?

Thanks
Vinoth

Comment: @VinothVino this seems worth a mention in the question as well

Comment: but testroid is not free

Comment: can you try giving some wait between actions like                                                     new TouchAction(driver).longPress(ele1).wait(somewait).moveTo(ele2).release.perform();

Comment: I already tried with wait. But appium throws an error for wait. Issue with wait is already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I believe drag drop most of the elements will be implemented as list and the 1st element should be clicked  at times before performing move actions

You can use the index of that element to move
try this

```
driver.findElements(By.id("your identifier")).get(0).click();
new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver).longPress(driver.findElements(By.id("your identifier")).get(0)).moveTo(driver.findElements(By.id("your identifier")).get(7)).release().perform();
```

Replace get(0),(7) by your index no of your id's

Comment: @ Karthick I have tried that possibility too.. I got same issue "drag dint complete successfully"

Comment: can u share the uiautomator view snippet for both elements

Comment: Sorry Karthick.  I am unable to post snippets since we have restriction over here.  What do you need from my other than this ?

Comment: i cannot comment more without seeing them